# Возвращает пустую строку при проверке $JAVA_HOME в ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

При проверке, что переменная среды установлена.
echo $JAVA_HOME

Команда возвращает пустую строку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расположена в файле .bashrc

> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64) export
>   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH

При проверке других GRADLE_HOME,M2_HOME сред команда возвращает установленный  путь.
Почему так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас неправильный синтаксис. Нужно

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

То, что у вас сейчас написано, присваивает переменной `JAVA_HOME` стандартный вывод команды `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, а т.к. такой команды не существует, вывод пустой.